# HTTP_PRAGMA manually inserted into $_SERVER

Tags: php, caching, server-variables

When we output the `$_SERVER` variable like this:

```
die('<pre>' . print_r($_SERVER, true) . '</pre>');
```

We'll get alot of taha, and between them these items:

```
[HTTP_CONNECTION] => keep-alive
[HTTP_CACHE_CONTROL] => max-age=0
```

When we to page reload `(Refresh button, CTRL+R or F5)`, they will remain there, and values will not be changed.

But when I press `CTRL + F5` (clear cache), a new item will appear under those two items:

```
[HTTP_PRAGMA] => no-cache
```

So my question is what shall browser do if I set:

```
$_SERVER['HTTP_PRAGMA'] = 'no-cache';
```

On top of my PHP scripts for every request? Will the browser **always** understand this as—clear cache for this web page?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_xxx']` are parameters sent from the browser to the server, not the other way around. If you want to send something to the browser, you use `header()`.

Comment: Besides that, *Pragma* is a request header field.

Answer (score 1):

A browser won't do anything. `$_SERVER` doesn't affect the *output* so the browser won't see it.

If you want to specify cache control rules for the browser, use `header()` and the [mnot guide to caching](http://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/).